# MySQL doesn't allow remote connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a MySQL running on the cloud, and I need to create users with select privileges to use in an application. Then, these users should be able to connect from the outside.

I did this:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO 'monty'@'%';
```

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is like this:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#skip-networking
```

However I'm unable to connect with `monty` outside localhost. MySQL Workbench gaves me error 10060

Comment: Starting at the source of inbound connections, a likely culprit is iptables. Is TCP 3306 open to remote hosts? libwrap is also a possiblilty if denied in `/etc/hosts.allow` or `/etc/hosts.deny`, but iptables is more probable.

Comment: Easily determined if you are able to open a connection from a remote machine with `telnet your.db.server 3306`.

Comment: is the IP address there (0.0.0.0) obfuscated by you for the purpose of the question, or is it exactly like that in the file?

Comment: probably real, cuz he smartly rem'd out skip-networking

Comment: @gabe3886 That's the method for binding MySQL to all inet interfaces rather than specifying one.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Cool.  I never knew that.  I'll leave that comment there in case other people don't know that either.

Comment: @gabe3886 it is like that on the file. if I put the real IP address MySQL crash and doesn't reboot

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` are empty

Comment: your options for bind-address are `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, remmed out with #, non-existing, or disaster. Pick one of the 5.

Comment: @Drew I tried all of them (except disaster, yet) and didn't made any effect

Comment: as Michael said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459000/mysql-doesnt-allow-remote-connections#comment52780171_32459000), can u get thru firewall ?

Comment: This is most likely the iptables firewall.  Test it with telnet from the remote site, check the output from `iptables -L` on the server.  A sane default setup would probably allow nothing through save for SSH. MySQL in most cases would require an explicit allowance.

Comment: iptables, firewall, http://superuser.com/a/791515

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I was denied on telnet too. output of `iptables -L`: http://i.imgur.com/UchQXY9.png

Comment: That looks like the firewall is open. Presuming you have restarted the mysql service to actually make it listen on the public IPs, you ought to be able to connect via telnet. Does your VM host's documentation say anything about filtered ports? It's not unheard of to block certain "dangerous" ports outright, but I wouldn't expect a VM infrastructure to do that. That would be verifiable by changing MySQL's port to something like 33306, allowing it in iptables, and trying to connect.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm using Amazon EC2... Perhaps I have to change something there.

Comment: done! updated my question. thanks @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the port on Amazon EC2 Management Console to work. Now I can access my MySQL server from outside.